# How to resize divs based on screen width with any approach

Tags: javascript, css, html, resize

I'm looking for suggestions on how to change the size of a div dynamically using the size of browser window. 
I've tried using css and can't get that to work as I can't use a percent value. I need the size of the divs to be (windowSize - 100)/3.
Any suggestions would be great thanks

Comment: Use the `window.onresize` event and get the window's size, plug it into your calculation, then change the divs' size

Comment: there's another potential cross browser solution to the one below using zoom if you are looking to maintain width / height proportion (windowSize is ambiguous and could refer to either or both dimensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS has something called `calc()` that can do that:

http://jsfiddle.net/YFFcD/1/

```
div {
    width: calc((100% - 100px) / 3);
}
```

The only real limitation is that it isn't supported by IE8 or older, or Opera.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

However, there may be ways around this by making use of other properties.  If paddings are causing the issue, use `box-sizing: border-box` (prefix as necessary).  If the elements must appear all in the same row, `display: table-cell` can be of some use:

http://jsfiddle.net/YFFcD/2/

```
div.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

div.container div {
    display: table-cell;
}

<div class="container">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.
I can't believe I couldn't find the calc() funtion.

Answer (score 0):

You could get `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`, do your calculations and then set the width and height of the `div`s explicitly:

```
$("#mydiv").css("width", (window.innerWidth - 100)/3);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with css.
Of course on a certain price the div won't have the block behavior
and some other layout dependent circumstances.

jsfiddle: [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hXzXT/)

**HTML example:**

```
<body>
    <div class="minus100">
        <div>One third</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.minus100 {
    position:fixed;
    /* or absolute; */
    top:0;
    left:50px;
    right:50px;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:blue;
}

div.minus100 div:first-child{ 
    width:33.3%;
    height:100%;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:navy;
}
```